# How to apply `data-trim` and `data-noescape` to a markdown code block in Reveal.js?

Tags: javascript, reveal.js

Is there any way to use the following two attributes in a markdown code block (rather than using HTML)?

`<code data-trim data-noescape>...</code>`

I tried adding these programmatically once the page has loaded but they don't get used (makes sense). I have also looked to see whether I can always have these settings by passing them as an option to `marked.js` / `markdown.js` but the plugins don't appear to allow this.

This relates to using Reveal.js - [see documentation](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js#code-syntax-highlighting).

Answer (score 1):

My current work around is using [inline html](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html) instead:

```
<pre><code class="bash" data-noescape data-trim>
    ...
</code></pre>
```

The [element attributes](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js#element-attributes) hack unfortunately doesn't seem to add empty attributes.